# python tuple, can someone explain this behavior?

Tags: python, tuples

I found some questions asking about `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment` on SO, but still, I'm confused about this:

Consider the code snippet:

```
>>> a = ([],[])
>>> a[0].append(1)       # 1
>>> a
([1], [])
>>> a[0] += [2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    a[0] += [2]
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment   # 2
>>> a
([1, 2], [])   # 3
>>>
```

My questions are:

1. tuples are immutable, but `1` successfully changed its value.Why?(I know I dont really understand python immutability..)
2. If `1` is accepted, what's the reason that `2` raise `TypeError`?
3. In `3`, `a` gets modified, then what's the point raising a `TypeError`?

Thank you

Comment: For the first, see http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types -- basically, "tuples are immutable" only means "you cannot add, remove or replace objects in a tuple", not "objects contained in a tuple are immutable too".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because tuples are immutable, but it can contain mutable data types( a *list* in ur case) as an element.

Your tuple `a = ([], [])` is a tuple of lists. So that's why you were able to append data to a[0] - which is a list.

In this:

```
a[0] += 2
```

You were attempting to change the value of the tuple which raises the exception TypeError (due to the use of '=' assignment operator)

In three, the list got concatenated due to the use of '+' operator.

Comment: -1 Your answer does not address how `a[0] += 2` attempts to modify the tuple, because naively, I would expect that to only modify the list object. `a[0]` is different from `a`.

Comment: a[0] = a[0] + [2], here the right hand side completed without an error(concatenation occured), and when the trying to assign the result to a[0] you are actually assigning a value to tuple, so it's throw an error. I might be wrong. But this is what I understood.